Xcode16 makes unnecessary SDL2 window when play button is pressed
I made a simple program which uses OpenGL and SDL2 library with Xcode16 editor:
#define GL_SILENCE_DEPRECATION
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <OpenGL/gl3.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 3);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
    
    SDL_Window* window = NULL;
    const int InitialWidth = 640;
    const int InitialHeight = 480;
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Shader", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, InitialWidth, InitialHeight, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    
    SDL_GLContext glContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);

    int quit = 0;
    while (!quit) {
        SDL_Event event;
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                quit = 1;
            }
        }
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.2f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
    }
    
    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(glContext);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}

When I build and run the program by pressing the play (shaped) button, two windows are executed with additional console terminal:

In addition, Xcode console display below error message:
CLIENT ERROR: TUINSRemoteViewController does not override -viewServiceDidTerminateWithError: and thus cannot react to catastrophic errors beyond logging them

This is not what I expected because my code only creates one window.
This problem happened after updating Xcode editor version from 15 to 16. It did not happened when I was using Xcode15. Is there anyone having similar problem with me?
Actually my original program was more complex than the above program. I rewrote the program from the start to found the point where problem happens. I found that creating SDL_Window and processing events made Xcode16 to execute program twice.

Does the extra window appear if you run the program outside of Xcode?

@Botje Extra window does not appear when I run the program outside of Xcode.
